# getting the substring that does not contain the first character in the string

Tags: c++, string, char

If the string was `abcdef` how do I get `bcdef`. I tried

```
 cout << str.substr(1,'\0')<< endl;
```

but that didn't work.

What about a char array?

Comment: no way you can get 'g' out of that string by using substr

Comment: `"bcdefg"` is **NOT** a substring of `"abcdef"`.

Comment: `cout << str.substr(1)`..dat works

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    std::string str = "abcdef";
    cout << str.substr (1);

    return 0;
}
```

Try it live: http://ideone.com/AueOXR

if you take a look at the documentation for string::substr:

```
string substr (size_t pos = 0, size_t len = npos) const;

Generate substring
Returns a newly constructed string object with its value initialized to a copy of a substring of this object.

The substring is the portion of the object that starts at character position pos and spans len characters (or until the end of the string, whichever comes first).
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

That means: if you don't specify a second parameter a default one that goes all the way to the end of the string is assumed.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 cout << str.substr(1)<< endl;
```

Of course, the documentation of string tells you everything you need to know ...

Answer (score 1):

Make it simpler:)

```
std::cout << str.substr( 1 ) << std::endl;
```

The other way and I think more effective is to use member function c_str if the string does not contain embedded zeroes

```
std::cout << str.c_str() + 1 << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

`substr(position, length)` will return the string started at the `position` index and ending at `length` characters after `position`.

You need to change the `\0` to either the end of the string index or to nothing because it will default to returning the rest of the string if you don't have a second parameter.

`str.substr(1)` will return `bcdef`

`str.substr(1, 5)` will also return `bcdef`